# asp:PlaceHolder inside asp:TableRow

Tags: asp.net, controls

I need this asp:TableRow to show conditionally.

```
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell><asp:Label id="ExtraAmountType" runat="server" Width="182px"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Right">$&nbsp;<asp:textbox id="MembershipDues" runat="server" Wrap="False" BackColor="#FFFF80" AutoPostBack="True" Width="31px" MaxLength="3" ontextchanged="MembershipDues_TextChanged"></asp:textbox></asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

How can I do this. I wrapped it in an

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="memberdues" runat="server">
```

tag but it complains:

Error   12  System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRowCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow'. 'asp:PlaceHolder' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder'.

I need this row to show conditionally.

I do this in Page_Load:

```
memberdues.Visible = false; 
if (DuesInfo.CredentialsAmount > 0)
{
    // do some other stuff to populate the variables in the placeholder then show it
    memberdues.Visible = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it an ID and set its runat to server then you can access it from code behind.

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="rowExtraAmountType">
```

Now it's accessible from an event from behind:

```
rowExtraAmountType.Visible = (conditional expression);
```

*Edit: Shown below with your question edits*

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="memberdues">
```

Then the code behind:

```
memberdues.Visible = (DuesInfo.CredentialsAmount > 0);
```